# Aspect Ratio, Height / Width in HTML-Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a square in which I want to draw a simple point,
The square width & height defined in percentage.
the problem is that the point comes out wrong (oval shaped).

[image]

I've created the following jsfiddle which reflects my issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/uhycv0pj/

```
<div style="width: 200px; height:200px; border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" style="width: 100%; height:100%; border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
</div>
<script>
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(50, 50, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
</script>
```

Comment: Try defining your canvas like this `<canvas id="myCanvas" style="width: 100%; height:100%; border:1px solid #d3d3d3;" width="200" height="200">`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qgwLf4e6/ this seems to draw a circle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to define the size of the Canvas in Pixels first:

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
c.width = 200
c.height = 200
```

You can also do it by "100%" with:

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
c.width = c.parentElement.clientWidth
c.height = c.parentElement.clientHeight
```

But remember, this wont change if your parent-element's width/height change. You will have to do it again - and setting a canvas' width/height will delete it's content, so you will have to draw it again.

DEMO:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
c.width = c.parentElement.clientWidth
c.height = c.parentElement.clientHeight
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(50, 50, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fill();
```

```html
<div style="width: 200px; height:200px; border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
<canvas id="myCanvas" style="width: 200px; height:200px; border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know the actual width and height, it's 200 only for this example.
I want to use precentages.

Comment: But you have to :( But you could check the size of the parent element